# How to create custom exceptions in Java?

Tags: java, exception

How do we create custom exceptions in Java?

Comment: It's the same methodology used in most OO languages: extend the base Exception class.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070590/how-can-i-write-an-exception-by-myself

Comment: 1) // Class that represents use-defined expception
class MyException extends Exception {
    public MyException(String s) {
        super(s);
    }
}
------------------------------------------------
2)

try
        {
            // Throw an object of user defined exception
            throw new MyException("TestException");
        }
        catch (MyException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Caught");
 
            // Print the message from MyException object
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

Answer (score 291, accepted):

To define a **checked** exception you create a subclass (or hierarchy of subclasses) of [`java.lang.Exception`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html).  For example:

```
public class FooException extends Exception {
  public FooException() { super(); }
  public FooException(String message) { super(message); }
  public FooException(String message, Throwable cause) { super(message, cause); }
  public FooException(Throwable cause) { super(cause); }
}
```

Methods that can potentially throw or propagate this exception must declare it:

```
public void calculate(int i) throws FooException, IOException;
```

... and code calling this method must either handle or propagate this exception (or both):

```
try {
  int i = 5;
  myObject.calculate(5);
} catch(FooException ex) {
  // Print error and terminate application.
  ex.printStackTrace();
  System.exit(1);
} catch(IOException ex) {
  // Rethrow as FooException.
  throw new FooException(ex);
}
```

You'll notice in the above example that [`IOException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html) is caught and rethrown as `FooException`.  This is a common technique used to encapsulate exceptions (typically when implementing an API).

Sometimes there will be situations where you don't want to force every method to declare your exception implementation in its throws clause.  In this case you can create an **unchecked** exception.  An unchecked exception is any exception that extends [`java.lang.RuntimeException`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) (which itself is a subclass of [`java.lang.Exception`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html)):

```
public class FooRuntimeException extends RuntimeException {
  ...
}
```

Methods can throw or propagate `FooRuntimeException` exception without declaring it; e.g.

```
public void calculate(int i) {
  if (i < 0) {
    throw new FooRuntimeException("i < 0: " + i);
  }
}
```

Unchecked exceptions are typically used to denote a programmer error, for example passing an invalid argument to a method or attempting to breach an array index bounds.

The [`java.lang.Throwable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) class is the root of all errors and exceptions that can be thrown within Java.  [`java.lang.Exception`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) and [`java.lang.Error`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) are both subclasses of [`Throwable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html).  Anything that subclasses [`Throwable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) may be thrown or caught.  However, it is typically bad practice to catch or throw [`Error`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) as this is used to denote errors internal to the JVM that cannot usually be "handled" by the programmer (e.g. [`OutOfMemoryError`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html)).  Likewise you should avoid catching [`Throwable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html), which could result in you catching [`Error`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html)s in addition to [`Exception`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html)s.

Answer (score 24):

```
public class MyException extends Exception {
        // special exception code goes here
}
```

Throw it as:

```
 throw new MyException ("Something happened")
```

Catch as:

```
catch (MyException e)
{
   // something
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For a checked exception:

```
public class MyCustomException extends Exception { }
```

Technically, anything that extends `Throwable` can be an thrown, but exceptions are generally extensions of the `Exception` class so that they're checked exceptions (except RuntimeException or classes based on it, which are not checked), as opposed to the other common type of throwable, `Error`s which usually are not something designed to be gracefully handled beyond the JVM internals.

You can also make exceptions non-public, but then you can only use them in the package that defines them, as opposed to across packages.

As far as throwing/catching custom exceptions, it works just like the built-in ones - throw via

```
throw new MyCustomException()
```

and catch via

```
catch (MyCustomException e) { }
```

Comment: RuntimeException extends Exception and is not a checked exception.

Comment: Technically, anything that extends `Throwable` can be *thrown*; exceptions extend `Exception`.  A custom subclass of Throwable would not be caught by a `try { ... } catch (Exception e) { ... }` block.

Comment: Why are people upvoting this answer? It contains a few inaccuracies. 1) You cannot *implmenet* throwable as it's an interface. 2) Anything that *extends* Throwable is **NOT** an exception (`Error` is not an exception, it's an error). 3) It implies that any subclass of Exception is checked whereas RuntimeException is not. The answer given by Adamski is much more accurate!

Comment: Oops - I meant throwable is **not** an interface of course!

Comment: @oxbow_lakes - the ideal solution would be to fix the inaccuracies, no? Anyhow, I've corrected them myself since no one else did.