# implementing a class in class

Tags: java, swing, error-handling, jsr296, jform

I am trying to implement a class in a class in JAVA, like this

```
package test;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
/**
 *
 * @author jackandjill
 */
public class Summingup extends JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Summingup
     */
    public Summingup() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        input1_tb = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        calculate_btn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        result_lbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        input2_tb = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Input 1");

        jLabel2.setText("Input 2");

        calculate_btn.setText("SUM");

        result_lbl.setText("RESULT DISPLAYED HERE!");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(input1_tb))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(result_lbl))
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(input2_tb)))))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(calculate_btn)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(1, 1, 1)
                        .addComponent(calculate_btn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addComponent(input1_tb, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(input2_tb, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 20, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(result_lbl)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * Set the Nimbus look and feel
         */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Summingup.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Summingup.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Summingup.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Summingup.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new Summingup().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton calculate_btn;
    private javax.swing.JTextField input1_tb;
    private javax.swing.JTextField input2_tb;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel result_lbl;
    // End of variables declaration
}

class InvalidValueException implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
         try
       {
           if(ae.getSource() ==calculate_btn)
           {
               String input_1 = input1_tb.getText();
                String input_2 = input2_tb.getText();

                checkBlanklnput(input_1,input_2);

                validateInput(Integer.parseInt(input_1),Integer.parseInt(input_2));

                result_lbl.setText(calculate(Integer.parseInt(input_1),Integer.parseInt(input_2)));

           }
       }

       catch (NumberFormatException excep)
       {
        result_lbl.setText("Invalid number");
       }
       catch (InvalidInputException excep)
       {
         result_lbl.setText(excep.getMessage());
       }
       catch (BlankInputException excep)
       {
         result_lbl.setText(excep.getMessage());
       }

    }



    public void checkBlanklnput(String input1,String input2) throws BlanklnputException 
    {
        if (input1.length() == 0 ||input2.length() == 0) throw new BlanklnputException();
    }

    public void validateInput(int input1 , int input2) throws InvalidInputException
    {

        if (input1 + input2 > 100 )
        throw new InvalidInputException();
    }

    public String calculate(int input1, int input2)
    {
        String res = "";
        while (true) 
        {
            res = Integer.toString(input1 + input2);
            break;
        }
        return res;

    }

}

class InvalidInputException extends Exception {

public InvalidInputException() {

super("Invalid number");

}
}
class BlankInputException extends Exception {

public BlankInputException() {

super("Input cannot be blank");

} 
 }
```

So this class is also throwing lot of exceptions and catching them. But the only problem is the JForm controls are not being recognised in the *InvalidValueException* class.
Not sure how to open those controls to this class.

Another issue that I am facing is my validateInput is checking for maximum sum but I want to check for IF any alphabets other than numbers are entered in the textboxes.

This is what my GUI looks like

[image]

Comment: That code is terrifying.. You are accused of giving me one sleepless night.. Please try to filter out that code, and post only relevant part..

Comment: @RohitJain I had to lol.

Comment: @RohitJain just a heads up, I used NETBEANS IDE and the rest is auto coded, so please make use of that...

Comment: @noobprogrammer.. How can one make use of that, if he doesn't have NetBeans IDE.. You should not make no assumptions..

Comment: @LewsTherin.. Lol :).. You should be sent to the dreams of a ghost.. :)

Comment: @RohitJain oh no its just a suggestion so I just said 'please' make use of that!

Comment: You can modify & throw your own excptions.
Take a look at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754315/how-to-create-our-own-exceptions-in-java

Comment: @noobprogrammer.. OK.. Couldn't get what you said.. Sorry.. Will try to make use of that.. :)

Comment: @RohitJain He is simply highlighting that he is using the JForm designer in NETBEANS IDE, but I think just copy and paste in to your own preferred IDE should do the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might compare your implementation to the working example shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8703807/230513). It uses `JFormattedTextField` to enforce numeric input, as well as a `PropertyChangeListener` & `FocusListener` to update the sum.

[image]

As an aside, you should study [layouts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) before relying too much on a GUI editor. See also [*Nested Classes*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

Addendum: `BlankInputException` was misspelled, and your (oddly named) `ActionListener` was unused. You should be able to initialize it using a custom code property.

```
calculate_btn.addActionListener(new InvalidValueException());
```

Comment: I have taken time to look thru the example that you have given but and nopticed that there is a constructor but in my case there is no construtor, is this the only way to address this problem? as you can see that mine is actually created using the IDE designer.

Comment: Absent the required `.form`, I can't edit your project, but your code worked after fixing the errors outlined above.