# Catching exception in java?

Tags: java, exception

I have below lines of code to catch the exceptions.

```
catch (Throwable ex) {
    //print stack trace         
}
```

and

```
catch (Exception ex) {
        //print stack trace         
    }
```

between the above two catch blocks, which one is recommended?

Thanks!

Comment: catch (Exception ex) {
        //print stack trace         
    }    is prefferd..

Comment: duplicate of duplicate :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Catching `Exception` is always recommended as `Throwable` will also catch the `Errors`.
Generally `Errors` are something Fatal and you should not continue.

Comment: For web service response can i use Throwable, because i will send customized response to clients. Thanks!

Comment: Use your own exceptions in this case. Your customized exception shall be subclass of Exception. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754315/how-to-create-our-own-exceptions-in-java

Answer (score 0):

`Exception` is Sub class of `Throwable`.

`Error` and `Exception` are 2 subclasses of Throwable. As suggested Errors results in something fatal(and hence should not be handeled). And Exception is programmatic issues  and should be handled by developer. And Hence `catch(Exception e)` is correct. Hope i made my point clear.