# Java Scanner if/else and while statements

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, java.util.scanner

I am trying to make a program that receives input from user, which is then used later on in the program. The problem I have is to make an exception. For example, if I only want the user to put in a number between 0 and whatever he previously put in. Here is an example:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("What length do you want your array to be?");
    int length = input.nextInt(); 
    int[] arr = full(length);
    print(arr);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Write a number between (0-"+length+"):");//Its here I want to add an exception.
    int number = input.nextInt();                       //if the user types in a greater value
    check(arr,number);                                  //of "length" or smaller value than 0
                                                        //I want the question to repeat itself
                                                        //until the criteria is met
```

You dont have to worry about the "check" or "print methods.

Comment: This could be useful: [`How to Create our own Exceptions in Java`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1754473/3928341) as well as this [`Oracle Docs Article`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Comment: Do you have to build your own Exception class? Or can you simply throw a new Exception?

Comment: I think there has been a missunderstanding, I meant a if/else or while statement which will not let the user type in values that does not meet the criteria. My english is not the best, so I apologize for that.

Comment: So you don't want to throw an exception, instead you just want to loop until the user inputs the right criteria?

Comment: An array really isn't necessary for this..

Comment: Yes, Johny.  I have tried using if/else statements, but It wont work for me.

Comment: @DrewKennedy we don't know what he's doing with the array, since we don't have the code for the `full(int)` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you need an `Exception`, just a loop. Like a `do-while` loop such as

```
int number;
do {
    System.out.println("Write a number between (0-" + length + "):");
    number = input.nextInt();
    if (number < 0) {
        System.out.printf("%d is too low%n", number);
    } else if (number > length) {
        System.out.printf("%d is too high%n", number);
    }
} while (number < 0 || number > length);
check(arr, number);
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need an exception, just add a `do-while` loop that checks whether it was a valid entry.

```
// ...

do
{
    System.out.println("Write a number between (0-"+length+"):");
    int number = input.nextInt();
} while( number < 0 || number >= length );
```

Note: I changed the condition to not include `length` since it appeared you were going to use that as an index to the array, and `length` is not a valid index in an array of length `length`.