# Creating Custom Exception

Tags: java

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754315/how-to-create-custom-exceptions-in-java) link as a reference for creating custom exceptions. For my class practice, if no file is selected or passed in, my custom UnknownFileException should occur, but when I go and run my driver and put in an invalid filename I get a nullpointerexception instead?

My driver which has `Adventure adventure = new Adventure(args[0])`.

My custom exception:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class UnknownFileException extends FileNotFoundException {

    public UnknownFileException() {
        super("We couldn't tell what file this is");    
    }

    public UnknownFileException(String message) {
        super(message);  
    }  
}
```

Code:

```
public class practice {
    public String[] array;
    public String line;
    public PrintWriter outputStream = null;
    public Scanner inputStream = null;

    public practice(String fileName) throws UnknownFileException {
        array = new String[100];

        try {
            inputStream = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));
            line = inputStream.nextLine();
            array[0] = line;

            for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
                array[i] = inputStream.nextLine();
            }
            outputStream = new PrintWriter(new  
                FileOutputStream("newFile.txt"));
         } catch(UnknownFileException e) {
             System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
             throw new UnknownFileException(e.getMessage());
         } finally {
             inputStream.close();  
         }
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably got a stack trace, which should have pointed you to the line throwing the `NullPointerException`.  I'm guessing it was this line:

```
inputStream.close();
```

The problem is that if you put in an invalid file name, `new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName))` will throw, and `inputStream` will never be assigned.  Because you have a `finally` block, however, before it throws your custom exception, it will try to execute the `finally`.  But this gives a `NullPointerException` because `inputStream` is `null`, and that exception takes precedence, I believe (I'd have to check the language rules to make sure of what happens in this case).

Fix your `finally` block to test whether `inputStream` is `null`.

**More:** It's [§14.20.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2) of the JLS.  This is pretty complicated, but basically if any exception is thrown from the `finally` block, any earlier exception thrown or caught is discarded.

Comment: I see, thank you very much! As soon as I get 15 reps I make sure to upvote your answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

`inputstream` is still `null`

Make the following change:

```
     } finally {
         if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
         }  
     }
```

or use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) instead.

Comment: I see, thank you very much! As soon as I get 15 reps I make sure to upvote your answer. Thanks again!