# What is type of exception to throw if property is not injected?

Tags: java, spring, exception

If module was not injected, in methodA which type of exception can i throw?

```
 public class Customer{
       private String module;

       public void methodA(){
         if (StringUtils.isBlank(module))
           throw new ???
       }
    }
```

Comment: Create your own `throw new BlankModuleException()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either create your own custom exception, or throw [`IllegalStateException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) along with an appropriate message. From the docs:

> Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time. In other words, **the Java environment or Java application is not in an appropriate state for the requested operation**. (emphasis mine)

Since you don't expect `module` to be blank, you're in an invalid state and hence this exception would be appropriate to throw in this case IMO.

Answer (score 0):

No Specfic predefined `Exception` is already there which you can make use of. So you can make a new one like `ModuleException`:-

```
public class ModuleException extends Exception {
  public ModuleException() { super(); }
  public ModuleException(String message) { super(message); }
  public ModuleException(String message, Throwable cause) { super(message, cause); }
  public ModuleException(Throwable cause) { super(cause); }
}
```

After creating `ModuleException` you can throw it in your class like:-

```
public void methodA(){
         if (StringUtils.isBlank(module))
           throw new ModuleException("Module is blank but is MANDATORY");
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would've said to use `NullPointerException` but the `isBlank` method also returns `true` when it's an empty String. The best option would probably be to make your own Exception (info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754315/how-to-create-custom-exceptions-in-java)). That way you also get complete customization.