# Is there a good exception class in JDK for the case where user input is too long?

Tags: java, exception

I'd like to process user input and throw an Exception if it exceeds some fixed limit of character. Example:

```
public String read(Reader r){
    String input;
    //get the input
    if(input.lenght() > 100)
         //throw what?
    return input;
}
```

Should I craft my own exception class for that case? I presume that just using `IllegalArgumentException` would not be fine.

Comment: What's wrong with `IllegalArgumentException`?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make your own Exception

Refer: [How to create custom exceptions in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754315/how-to-create-custom-exceptions-in-java)

Try this:

```
public String read(Reader r){
    String input;
    //get the input
    if(input.lenght() > 100)
         throw new Exception("Write your own stuff");
    return input;
}
```