# Is there another method to replace Exception message with custom message instead of try{}catch(Exception e){} method?

Tags: java

Instead of the `try{}catch(Exception e){}` method, is there a way to just state a custom message that replaces the exception message when exceptions like InputMismatchException, NoSuchElementException etc. occurs anywhere on the program?

EDIT: I want another method because if I use `try{}catch(Exception e){}` method than I will have to do it everywhere and the code also becomes longer.

For example:

```
public static String genderOutput()
    {

        try
        {

            System.out.print("\nMale   - 1 \nFemale - 2 \n\nEnter either 1 or 2: ");

            int genderInput = userInput.nextInt();

            if(genderInput == 1)
            {

                String userGender = "Mr.";

                return userGender;

            }

            else if(genderInput == 2)
            {

                String userGender = "Mrs.";

                return userGender;

            }

            else
            {

                String userGender = " ";

                return userGender;

            }

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {

            return null;

        }

    }
```

I have this function, now if there were multiple functions in a class like this then I would have to have the `try{}catch(Exception e){}` method everywhere. Wouldn't it be more efficient if you can just replace the exception message with your own and when such exception occurs which has a custom message stated to them then it would just throw out the custom message instead. This way, the code will be shorter as well.

**SOLUTION TO MY PROBLEM:**

```
public class Test
{

    public static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static String titleName = "TheRivalsRage";
    public static String exitLevelMessage = "Program exited!";
    public static String errorMessageTitle = "\n[Error] ";

    public static String intInputMismatchException = "Please enter an Integer Value!";
    public static String intNoSuchElementException = "Please enter either '1' or '2' without the quotes!";
    public static String lineNoSuchElementException = "Please enter something!";
    public static String bothIllegalStateException  = "Scanner closed unexpectedly!";

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws Exception
    {

        String usernameOutput;
        String userGender;

        try
        {

            System.out.print("Enter your username: ");

            usernameOutput = userInput.nextLine();

            userGender = genderOutput();

            userInput.close();

        }

        catch(IllegalStateException e)
        {

            throw new IllegalStateException(errorMessageTitle + bothIllegalStateException);

        }

        if(userGender == null)
        {

            noSuchElementException();

        }

        else
        {

            System.out.println("\nWelcome " + userGender + " " + usernameOutput + " to " + titleName);

        }

    }

    public static String genderOutput()
    {

        String userGender;

        int genderInput;

        System.out.print("\nMale   - 1 \nFemale - 2 \n\nEnter either 1 or 2: ");

        try
        {

            genderInput = userInput.nextInt();

        }

        catch(InputMismatchException e)
        {

            genderInput = 0;

            inputMismatchException();

        }

        if(genderInput == 1)
        {

            userGender = "Mr.";

        }

        else if(genderInput == 2)
        {

            userGender = "Mrs.";

        }

        else
        {

            userGender = null;

        }

        return userGender;

    }

    public static void inputMismatchException()
            throws InputMismatchException
    {

        throw new InputMismatchException(errorMessageTitle + intInputMismatchException);

    }

    public static void noSuchElementException()
            throws NoSuchElementException
    {

        throw new NoSuchElementException(errorMessageTitle + intNoSuchElementException);

    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Not really.  Do you have a problem with try-catch?

Comment: The only thing you can do (if it's *your own* that is throwing the exception) is to throw it like this: `throw new InputMismatchException("Message");`

Comment: Please read the Edited Line. I just want to know if there is a much more efficient way to do it. Don't just down-vote it.

Comment: Are you talking writing your own Exception class?? I think this link will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1754473/8412149

Comment: Kind of like that, just wanted to replace certain types of exceptions with a custom message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't handle exception in each and every method just use **throws Exception** after method signature  and handle it at end where the methods are being called.
and there in catch block you can throw your custom exception.

```
 void method1() throws Exception{
//
}

void method2() throws Exception{
//
}

   void finalmethod(){
        try{
          method1();

          method2();

        }catch(InputMismatchException e){
                  throw customExcpetion("custommessage1");
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw customExcpetion("custommessage2");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks so much for the help! I find this one to be much easier and efficient so far.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `try`/`catch`.

However, you do not need to catch *all* exceptions separately, because the exceptions that you mention are all subclasses of `RuntimeException`. Hence, it is sufficient to make a single `try`/`catch` in your `main` to intercept `RuntimeException`, and print the replacement message:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ... // Actual code
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        System.err.println("A runtime error has occurred.");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a better way of doing it but will it work on functions when they are called as well?

Comment: But for example: InputMismatchException and NoSuchElementException are different errors so they'll have their own message and not a single message.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Aspectj or Spring aop by creating  around advice. You can replace message by catching exception inside advice and rethrow.

Check http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-aop/aspectj-around-advice-example/
To know about how to use spring aop for anound advice

Comment: I'm a beginner so that will be too much for me right now. I just want some kind of method on the Java itself.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't provide this feature out of the box but nobody prevents you to create a class that composes a `Scanner` object and that decorates methods that you are using as  `nextInt()`.

Inside the decorated method, invoke `nextInt()`, catch the exception that it may throw and handle it by returning `null` as in your question.
If it makes sense, you could even provide a `nextInt()` method with a default value as parameter if the input fails.

```
public class MyCustomScanner{

   private Scanner scanner;
   ...
   public Integer nextInt(){
       try{       
            return scanner.nextInt()
       }
       catch(InputMismatchException e){
           myStateObj.setErrorMessage("....");
           return null;
       }
   }
   public Integer nextInt(Integer defaultValue){
       try{       
            return scanner.nextInt()
       }
       catch(InputMismatchException e){
           myStateObj.setErrorMessage("....");
           return defaultValue;
       }
   }
}
```

Now you can use the class in this way :

```
MyCustomScanner scanner = new MyCustomScanner();
Integer intValue = scanner.nextInt();
Integer otherIntValue = scanner.nextInt(Integer.valueOf(4));
```