# Can I go straight to exception on a certain condition?

Tags: java, try-catch

I created a number format try catch: which is something like this

```
try{
      int blabla = sc.nextInt();
   } catch (numberFormatException E) {
     doSomething();
   }
```

How can I go straight to the catch, if say, `blabla > 100`?
Can I go straight to the catch, without having a number format exception, and using if statements? The try catch is mainly for when a string is entered.

Comment: use throw new NumberFormatException() if your blabla>100 inside the try block.

Comment: You ... don't seem to understand what catch blocks are for.

Comment: @BrianRoach This forum is not a place for you to judge what i know and what I dont. I'm here to learn. If you have any useful advice give it, otherwise, don't comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why do you need try catch ? you can simply use if statement

```
int blabla = sc.nextInt();
if(blabla > 100 )
    doSomeThing();
```

**UPDATED**

as per your comment if you want to catch  you can throw the exception like following

```
    try{
          int blabla = sc.nextInt();
          if(blabla > 100)
              throw new NumberFormatException();
       } catch (NumberFormatException E) {
              doSomeThing();
       }
```

**MORE UPDATE**

after the Brian comment i realized I should update a bit more. Yes it is definitely wrong to throw an exception for other cases. like here if `blabla > 100` then it is not a `NumberFormatException`. So the better case would be to create your own exception and throw and catch that. to create a custom exception you can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070590/how-can-i-write-an-exception-by-myself)

But i still think the if statement is good for your case.

Comment: Honestly, telling someone how to do something the absolute wrong way is just ... wrong.

Comment: @BrianRoach It's not *that* wrong. Why precisely are you so antagonistic about it? Just because it conflates the range error with the number format error?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik No, because to quote Josh Bloch "Exceptions are for exceptional conditions". They shouldn't be used for flow control. It really *is* that bad of a practice, and I hate seeing beginner programmers get bad advice.

Comment: @BrianRoach But a number exceeding 100 is as much exceptional as it not being a parseable number. If you extracted all that to a method, which would throw an `InvalidNumberException`, you would call that equally bad? Why, and if not, what exactly is the key difference?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik conditional != exceptional. Seriously, his book has a whole section on why not to do this :)

Comment: @BrianRoach Furthermore, just quoting Josh Bloch isn't enough, especially in the exceptions area. His position on checked exceptions is widely violated (Spring/Hibernate), to everyone's relief.

Comment: @BrianRoach I've read the book... a *long* time ago. Even then that item seemed shady to me, now only more so. Note that the example he uses in the book really is extreme, but his generalization extends far too broadly. Exceptions are *all about control flow*.

Comment: @BrianRoach BTW behind any *exception* there's a *condition* in which it is thrown. So your equation doesn't quite add up.

Comment: to be honest I didn't think in depth while answering the question. the first option was my answer. But later from the asker's comment i think he is trying to find a way to throw an exception for custom cases. So here comes the second edit. But again i realaized that for custom cases we should create a custom exception ..

Comment: @StinePike Can you name a solid reason *why*? Assuming that handling is exactly the same for all invalid numbers, regardless of the detailed reason (unparseable, out of range).

Comment: please pardon me , i didn't understood your question properly @MarkoTopolnik

Comment: Why do you think this calls for a custom exception, which is about 20 lines of boilerplate code? Just to give it a more "politically correct" name? Since the distance between the `throw` and the `catch` is less than a screenful of code, there's little room for confusion.

Comment: i was assuming that he might need to catch a exception for custom case. not only for blabla > 100; just another option.. Also do you think it is good to throw NumberFormatException where it is not actually a caused for invalid number format? And again, the final edit was not only for this question. I mentioned another options for custom need. Please correct my thinking if I am wrong @MarkoTopolnik

Comment: `do you think it is good to throw NumberFormatException where it is not actually a caused for invalid number format`---my position on this is the content of my previous comment :) In plainer words: ideally the exception would have a more appropriate name, but it is not worth the extra boilerplate which will be required to declare the custom exception class.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yes i agree with you with this point. But i was thinking in a different view. think about a big case instead of simple range checking. I mentioned this only for showing alternative options. but for this case only I think simple if statement is the best case. what do you think?

Comment: If `doSomething` is not just one method call, and it isn't always trivial to extract code into a method (code may depend on many local variables, it may assign to them, there may be multiple exit points...), then your `if` approach results in duplicated code.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are trying to achieve.

```
try{
  int blabla = sc.nextInt();
  if (blabla > 100) {
    throw new NumberFormatException();
  }
} catch (NumberFormatException E) {
  doSomething();
}
```

Comment: This is really horrible thing to do, ignoring that it "works".

Comment: yeah, he should probably create its own exception (sort of NumberTooBigException) and throw that.

Comment: He may be trying to learn how to catch exception in a peculiar way. =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
try{
      int blabla = sc.nextInt();
      if(blabla > 100) 
            throw new NumberFormatException();
   } catch (numberFormatException E) {
     doSomething();
   }
```

EDIT : Stay with if..else until and unless you have specific requirement to go with throw exception and catch it...