# Handling a custom exception

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to create a custom exception "UserNotFoundException" that will be thrown when a GET request for a user that doesn't exist comes in.

```
class UserNotFoundException extends Exception {

    public UserNotFoundException(Long id) {
        super(id);
    }
}
```

I know super(id) won't work, but I have no idea how to deal with this problem. The exception is thrown here:

```
@GetMapping("/users/{id}")
    User one(@PathVariable Long id) {

        return repository.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(id));
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `super("User " + id + " not found");`

Comment: Thanks, changed it, but now I'm getting an error: "Unhandled exception type UserNotFoundException" at the return statement

Comment: Well... that's your exception you just created? Your function header should state `throws UserNotFoundException` after the function declaration, but before the function body.

Comment: You're using a checked exception which requires handling at compile time. You are probably looking to extend a `RuntimeException`

Comment: thanks!! That fixed it

Comment: is this an HTTP/REST endpoint handler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attempting to call a parent constructor that does not exist.

```
class UserNotFoundException extends Exception {

    public UserNotFoundException(Long id) {
        super(id);
    }

}
```

The `Exception` class provides you have the following constructors:

```
public Exception()
public Exception(String message)
public Exception(String message, Throwable cause)
public Exception(Throwable cause)
protected Exception(String message, Throwable cause,
                    boolean enableSuppression,
                    boolean writableStackTrace)
```

If you would like to see a message come through with the `id` you will have to convert your `Long` to a `String`.

```
public UserNotFoundException(Long id) {
    super(String.valueOf(id));
}
```

You also have the ability to have custom fields for your UserNotFoundException if you intend on leveraging `ExceptionHandler`

```
private Long id;
public UserNotFoundException(Long id) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
}

// Getters
```

**Why it fails when converting the message to a string: Checked vs Unchecked Exceptions**
Keep in mind that `Exception` is a checked exception which requires you to have explicit handling for -- otherwise, this will fail at compile time.

You may want to look into `RuntimeException` to set up an unchecked exception.

See the following for more details on `RuntimeException` vs `Exception`:

[Difference between java.lang.RuntimeException and java.lang.Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190161/difference-between-java-lang-runtimeexception-and-java-lang-exception)

See the following for a similar question and answers that can point you in the right direction:

[How can I write custom Exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070590/how-can-i-write-custom-exceptions)